# apply escaping for regex matches

Tags: java, regex

I have such replacement statement

```
output.replaceAll(REGEX_BRACKETS, "&lt;$2$3&gt;");
```

How to apply escaping via (`StringEscapeUtils` for example) for `$2` and `$3`?

Comment: AFAIK, if you want to operate on the strings replaced by `$x` in regex, you need to use `Matcher.group()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how this can be done inside `Matcher`:

```
String s = "word 123 some text inside next 567";
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\s+(\\d+)").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    String wrd = m.group(1);
    String num = m.group(2);
    String replacement = wrd.toUpperCase() + num;
    m.appendReplacement(result, replacement);
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/ZIDZZb)

Just use your own functions, I am using `toUpperCase()` just for demo.